# Version Issue in integrating mobx-react in app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, mobx-react

I received this error for my app sample-login-page while running `npm update`

> ```
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! While resolving: sample-login-page@1.0.0
> npm ERR! Found: mobx-react@5.4.4
> npm ERR! node_modules/mobx-react
> npm ERR!   mobx-react@"5.4.4" from the root project
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer mobx-react@"^4.3.5" from bernie-core@0.41.4
> npm ERR! node_modules/bernie-core
> npm ERR!   peer bernie-core@">=0.24.7" from bernie-test-util@0.35.4
> npm ERR!   node_modules/bernie-test-util
> npm ERR!     dev bernie-test-util@"0.35.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer bernie-core@">=0.25.0" from @gc/global-controls-store@0.1.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@gc/global-controls-store
> npm ERR!     @gc/global-controls-store@"^0.1.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!     1 more (bernie-test-util)
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> ```

After upgrading mobx-react by `npm install mobx-react --save` I came up with same errors.
After installing mobx-react with specifically required version `npm i mobx-react@4.3.5`. Below error is coming up

> ```
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! While resolving: sample-login-page@1.0.0
> npm ERR! Found: mobx@4.15.4
> npm ERR! node_modules/mobx
> npm ERR!   mobx@"4.15.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer mobx@"^3.4.1 || ^4.0.0" from bernie-core@0.41.4
> npm ERR!   node_modules/bernie-core
> npm ERR!     peer bernie-core@">=0.24.7" from bernie-test-util@0.35.4
> npm ERR!     node_modules/bernie-test-util
> npm ERR!       dev bernie-test-util@"0.35.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!     peer bernie-core@">=0.25.0" from @gc/global-controls-store@0.1.3
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@gc/global-controls-store
> npm ERR!       @gc/global-controls-store@"^0.1.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!       1 more (bernie-test-util)
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer mobx@"^2.6.3 || ^3.0.0" from mobx-react@4.3.5
> npm ERR! node_modules/mobx-react
> npm ERR!   mobx-react@"4.3.5" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer mobx-react@"^4.3.5" from bernie-test-util@0.35.4
> npm ERR!   node_modules/bernie-test-util
> npm ERR!     dev bernie-test-util@"0.35.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!   2 more (@gc/global-controls-store, bernie-core)
> ```

Can someone help me out with suggestions around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this :

```
npm install mobx-react --save --legacy-peer-deps
```